# I have to persist a Map<EntityType, List<EntityType>> with JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-annotations

I'm trying to persist an Entity that has a Map as one of its values. To be more precise. I have the @Entity Request that have a compound primary key with three elements. This primary key is composed by an id, the User an `Map<EntityType, List<EntityType>>` where the first EntityType is the selected service and the related value is the list of the items where the service will be applied to.
Below the code that I have but I'm missing the annotation that i have to use for the Map. I read online that the good way to go is the create a wrapper entity like to one that i created (SelectedService2MyItem) that holds the list and then the map is just a key-value pair between two entity but I can't make it works and I don't know how to proceed. 
Does anyone can help me?

**Request Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Request {

    @EmbeddedId
    private RequestId id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_user_id"), nullable=false)
    private User user;
//Getter, setter, constructor omitted
}
```

**RequestId**

```
@Embeddable
public class RequestId {

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "FK_user_id"), nullable=false)
private User user;

private Map<ServiceOffered, SelectedService2MyItem> service2MyItem = new HashMap<ServiceOffered, SelectedService2MyItem>();

//Getter, setter, constructor omitted
}
```

**SelectedService2MyItem**

```
@Entity
public class SelectedService2MyItem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id")
    private List<MyItem> myItemsSelected;

//Getter, setter, constructor omitted
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: The error is related to the missing mapping for the Map service2MyItem, but i don't know how the mapping with annotations should be. Here the error:  `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Map, at table: request, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(service2my_item)]`